# Fix char formatting error - Linux system C program

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I am trying to get rid of the error in my program. I'm not sure what is wrong with the array.

Here is the sample code:

```
typedef struct listNoNodes
{
 char FirstName[50];
 char LastName[60];
 int ID;
 int age;
 struct listNoNodes* next;
} listNoNodes;


listNoNodes* listNodes(char FirstName[], char LastName[], int ID, int age,
listNoNodes* next)
{
 listNoNodes* tmp = (listNoNodes*)malloc(sizeof(listNoNodes));
 tmp->FirstName[50] = FirstName;
 tmp->LastName[60] = LastName;
 tmp->ID = ID;
 tmp->age = age;
 tmp->next = next;
 return tmp;
};
```

Here is the error

```
lab3.c: In function ‘listNodes’:
lab3.c:21:21: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 |  tmp->FirstName[50] = FirstName;
      |                     ^
lab3.c:22:20: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   22 |  tmp->LastName[60] = LastName;
```

Comment: `tmp->FirstName[50]` is element number `51` in your `50`-element array. It's a *single element*. Please take some time to refresh your text-books and what they say about strings and arrays.

Comment: What does "_I would like scanf to be used to read and save the char inputs._" to do with the error? Don't mix in unrelated questions. The question just became unclear. Ask a separate question if you can't get `scanf` working. I rolled back your `scanf` addition.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are wrong:

```c
tmp->FirstName[50] = FirstName;
tmp->LastName[60] = LastName;
```

You are trying to assign `char*` pointers to single `char` elements.

You need to copy the *contents* of the arrays instead, eg:

```c
strncpy(tmp->FirstName, FirstName, 50);
strncpy(tmp->LastName, LastName, 60);
```

Comment: You might want to add a warning that the `strncpy` calls might not add the null terminator.

Comment: How do I make it so this command can be used to scanf for the first and last name?

Comment: @Brendan that is a completely different question, so I suggest you make a new post for it. This question has been answered as asked.

Comment: I updated the post, if you could edit the answer and I will give it an up arrow and a check! :)

Comment: @Brendan I asked you to post a new question about that scanf issue, not to edit this question. I see that your update was rolled back (I didn't do that, but I agree with it). This is an Q&A site, keep questions clear and concise, one question per post, please.